# TurboFilter for limiting exception that are logged - not working

Tags: java, filter, logback

I created a TurboFilter for limiting the exception , using logback's TurboFilter.

**Here is the code:**

```
package com.example;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import org.slf4j.Marker;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.TurboFilter;
import ch.qos.logback.core.spi.FilterReply;

public class ExceptionFilter extends TurboFilter {

    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long> exceptionCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private long suppressTimeInMS = 10 * 60 * 1000;

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
    }

    @Override
    public FilterReply decide(Marker marker, Logger logger, Level level, String format, Object[] params, Throwable t) {

        FilterReply reply = FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
        long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (null != t) {
            String exceptionName = t.getClass().getName();
            if (!exceptionCache.containsKey(exceptionName)) {
                exceptionCache.put(exceptionName, currTime);
                reply = FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
            }
        else {
            long previousTime = exceptionCache.get(exceptionName);
            if ((currTime - previousTime) >= suppressTimeInMS) {
                exceptionCache.put(exceptionName, currTime);
                reply = FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
            }
            else {
                reply = FilterReply.DENY;
            }
        }
    }

    return reply;
    }

    public void setSuppressTimeInMS(long suppressTimeInMS) {
        this.suppressTimeInMS = suppressTimeInMS;
    }
}
```

In this I have created a `ConcurrentHashMap` which will store `Exception` as key and `timestamp` as value. I am not using any `Cache`.

The logic is , for a `suppressTimeInMS` time it will block (by replying DENY) and once it is over, then it will allow logging.

However, it is not working as I expected.

So i am looking for some inputs if there are some issues in this implementation?